# Switch languages with Right Alt and Right Shift (Linux Mint 20)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to switch between two languages by <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> buttons, but it's not found in Linux Mint 20 Layout Options. I tried to choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and none for the compose key. The <kbd>L Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switches well, but not the <kbd>R Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I also tried `XKPOPTIONS` as shown in the second picture but it's also not working!

[image]

**`/etc/default/keyboard`**

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ara"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt,lv3:lalt_switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Run `xev` and check whether your right Alt generates the correct event.

Comment: I'm new to linux, can you tell me how to do it, please?

Comment: can you take a look to the second picture in my post?